# PyQt: getting widgets to resize automatically in a QDialog

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qdialog

I'm having difficulty getting widgets in a QDialog resized automatically when the dialog itself is resized.

In the following program, the textarea resizes automatically if you resize the main window.  However, the textarea within the dialog stays the same size when the dialog is resized.

Is there any way of making the textarea in the dialog resize automatically?  I've tried using `setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)` on the dialog itself and the two widgets within, but that seems to have no effect.

I'm using Qt version 3.3.7 and PyQt version 3.5.5-29 on openSuSE 10.2, if that's relevant.

```
import sys
from qt import *

# The numbers 1 to 1000 as a string.
NUMBERS = ("%d " * 1000) % (tuple(range(1,1001)))

# Add a textarea containing the numbers 1 to 1000 to the given
# QWidget.
def addTextArea(parent, size):
    textbox = QTextEdit(parent)
    textbox.setReadOnly(True)
    textbox.setMinimumSize(QSize(size, size*0.75))
    textbox.setText(NUMBERS)


class TestDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setCaption("Dialog")
        everything = QVBox(self)

        addTextArea(everything, 400)
        everything.resize(everything.sizeHint())


class TestMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setCaption("Main Window")
        everything = QVBox(self)

        addTextArea(everything, 800)

        button = QPushButton("Open dialog", everything)
        self.connect(button, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.openDialog)        

        self.setCentralWidget(everything)
        self.resize(self.sizeHint())

        self.dialog = TestDialog(self)

    def openDialog(self):
        self.dialog.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwin = TestMainWindow(None)
    app.setMainWidget(mainwin)
    mainwin.show()
    app.exec_loop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QMainWindow has special behavior for the central widget that a QDialog does not. To achieve the desired behavior you need to create a [layout](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/layout.html), add the text area to the layout and assign the layout to the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a little note about this - I was trying to have a child window spawned from an application, which is a `QDialog`, containing a single `QTextEdit` as a child/content - and I wanted the `QTextEdit` to resize automatically whenever the `QDialog` window size changes. This seems to have done the trick for me with `PyQt4`:

```
def showTextWindow(self):

  #QVBox, QHBox # don't exist in Qt4

  dialog = QDialog(self)
  #dialog.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))
  dialog.setWindowTitle("Title")
  dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

  textbox = QTextEdit(dialog)
  textbox.setReadOnly(True)
  textbox.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400*0.75))
  textbox.setText("AHAAA!")

  # this seems enough to have the QTextEdit 
  # autoresize to window size changes of dialog!
  layout = QHBoxLayout(dialog)
  layout.addWidget(textbox)
  dialog.setLayout(layout)

  dialog.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had looked at using a QLayout before but had no luck.  I was trying to do something like

```
dialog.setLayout(some_layout)
```

but I couldn't get that approach to work so I gave up.

My mistake was that I was trying to pass the layout to the dialog when I should have been passing the dialog to the layout.

Adding the lines

```
layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
layout.add(everything)
```

to the end of `TestDialog.__init__` fixes the problem.

Thanks to Monjardin for prompting me to reconsider layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Python QT Automatic Widget Resizer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqtresize/) It's suppose to work well.