# PyQt Window not show after setting layout for centralWidget

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm making a PyQt application, and the UI file was designed using Qt Designer. Its initial structure is like this:

```
MainWindow
- CentralWidget
  - PaintWidget (which was promoted from QWidget)
```

Since the paintwidget doesn't resize when the window is maximized, I added a layout to the centralwidget in MainWindow class according to the suggestion here: [PyQt: getting widgets to resize automatically in a QDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406939/pyqt-getting-widgets-to-resize-automatically-in-a-qdialog)

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)
        top_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(top_layout)
        top_layout.addWidget(self.paintwidget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

However, the application window doesn't show any more. When I ran it in Wing IDE, the debug process just exited instantly.

I also tried setting layout for centralWidget in Qt Designer directly, but the application doesn't execute either. Why?

Comment: There are at least two potential errors in your script: (1) missing imports, and (2) misspelled attributes. Is Wing IDE not able to show tracebacks? Maybe you should try running the script in a console so you can get some proper feedback on what the errors are.

Comment: PyQt doesn't display error output by default. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493081/pyqt-event-handlers-snarf-exceptions for how to get the error.