# How to stick widgets side by side

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qcombobox, qdialog

The code below creates a dialog window with three widgets: QLabel, QComboBox and QButton.

I want QLabel and QComboBox to be sitting on a same line. That is why both of these widgets are assigned to the same horizontal layout.
Resizing the dialog creates a huge empty space between the Label and ComboBox. How to assure that the left side of the Combo sticks to the right side of Label when dialog is resizing?

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
app = QApplication([])


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout().addLayout(h_layout)
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setText('Month:')
        combo = QComboBox(self)
        h_layout.addWidget(label)
        h_layout.addWidget(combo)
        button = QPushButton('Ok')
        self.layout().addWidget(button)
        self.resize(200, 50)
        self.show()


dialog = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: HAve you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406939/pyqt-getting-widgets-to-resize-automatically-in-a-qdialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to establish the size policy through `QSizePolicy`, in your case you must set the policy `QSizePolicy::Expanding` in the horizontal component of the `QComboBox`:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout().addLayout(h_layout)
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setText('Month:')

        combo = QComboBox(self)
        policy = combo.sizePolicy()
        policy.setHorizontalPolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        combo.setSizePolicy(policy)

        h_layout.addWidget(label)
        h_layout.addWidget(combo)
        button = QPushButton('Ok')
        self.layout().addWidget(button)
        self.resize(200, 50)
        self.show()


dialog = Dialog()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shorter and better solution is add parameter `stretch=1` to addWidget() function:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
app = QApplication([])

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout().addLayout(h_layout)
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setText('Month:')
        combo = QComboBox(self)
        h_layout.addWidget(label)
        h_layout.addWidget(combo, stretch=1)
        button = QPushButton('Ok')
        self.layout().addWidget(button)
        self.resize(200, 50)
        self.show()

dialog = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```